# How can I pack the frame over the graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a graphic and would like to have the dark gray border over the world map. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_map(data=world.inp, 
           map=world.inp, 
           aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region), fill = "grey80")+
  xlim(min(dat$decimalLongitude, na.rm = T),
       max(dat$decimalLongitude, na.rm = T))+
  ylim(min(dat$decimalLatitude, na.rm = T), 
       max(dat$decimalLatitude, na.rm = T))+
  geom_point(data = dat, 
             size = 0.7, 
             shape = 16,
             aes(x = decimalLongitude, 
                 y = decimalLatitude,
                 col = species))+
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_minimal()+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 3)))+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(size=1, linetype="solid", 
                                        colour ="grey50"),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'cm'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(0.1, 'cm'),
        legend.title.align = 0,
        legend.position = c(0.9, 0.18),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.9, 'cm'),
        legend.title = element_text(size=9), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=8), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey95",
                                         size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                         colour ="grey50"))
```

[image]

Comment: What about the species legend in the corner?

Comment: It's where it's supposed to be. But should please also remain in the foreground

Comment: `+ theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey50", fill = NA))`?

Comment: Did not work unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA,
                                size=1.3, linetype="solid", 
                                colour ="grey50")
```